# OS X 10.11 GM Candidate 1 left my Mac unable to boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, bootable-disk, macos

I tried to install the OS X 10.11 GM to my 2012 Macbook Air, and it crashed during the install.  I tried to go into recovery mode to reinstall OS X, but once I put in my Wifi password and press the install button it crashes and reboots.

Is there some way to reinstall OS X short of taking it to an Apple Store?  The nearest store is about a 3 hour drive away, so if I can do this from home I'd prefer that.

The Macbook Air of course doesn't have a disc drive, but I know in the past with Lion you could get a USB stick from Apple to upgrade the OS.  I'm wondering if I could either get a USB from Apple or make my own?

As a last resort is it possible to ship my Macbook to Apple to be repaired?

Comment: Do you have another Macintosh to use? (Also a Friends Macbook - you will only need it for a few minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have a recent backup? If not this procedure will be substantially different.

## Backed Up? Use Recovery Mode

If you boot into [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314) using  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at startup can you proceed with an internet recovery by installing over top of the hosed OS already on the drive?

If that works I would try that first. It **should** leave your files and apps alone for the most part. If it fails then you may have to reformat the Mac OS partition and install clean using Internet recovery.

### No Back Up? Use Target Disk Mode

If you do not have a backup you may have to put your system into [target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19021) by holding <kbd>T</kbd> at startup and hooking it up to another Mac with a Thunderbolt cable to back up your files.

Comment: Questions regarding iOS 9 and OS X El Capitan are considered on-topic. See here: http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2015/08/beta-ios-9-and-el-capitan-questions-allowed/